# Numeric time zone handling in Python with time module

Tags: python, time

I have the following Python code:

```
import json
import fileinput
import time

ts_pattern  = '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S +0000]'

for line in fileinput.input():
    json_data = json.loads(line)
    etime = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(json_data['time_local'], ts_pattern)))
    print etime
```

I have made a mistake, it appears.  For example, in the JSON that I'm reading, `time_local` is `[06/Oct/2015:15:29:35 +0000]`.  My script outputs 1444166975 as the result.  However, that is not correct, so far as I can see:

```
$ date -ud @1444166975
Tue Oct  6 21:29:35 UTC 2015
```

Having the linux `date` command do the conversion back gives:

```
$ date +%s -ud "06-Oct-2015 15:29:35 +0000"
1444145375
```

So far as I understand (which could easily be wrong...), I want the output to be in GMT in order for the conversion to epoch to be correct.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `time.mktime()` with UTC time. It accepts local time and therefore your code is wrong if your local timezone is not UTC.

Use [`calendar.timegm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from calendar import timegm

tt = time.strptime('[06/Oct/2015:15:29:35 +0000]',
                   '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S +0000]')
print(timegm(tt))  # -> 1444145375
```

See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Comment: I always like the "How do I...?", "You don't" posts, as they seem to reveal new things about a language.  That worked.  Thank you very much.